# Unable to run Visual Studio on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.4 and I am unable to run Visual Studio Code.
It simply says

> The application “Visual Studio Code” can’t be opened.

**I tried**:

1. right-click and *Open*
2. Going to System Preferences » Security & Privacy. It didn't have the button 'Open Visual Studio Code anyway'
3. Moving the app to the Applications folder and running `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

None of these helped.

Screenshot is attached.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open:`System Preferences > Security & Privacy`, navigate to the `General` tab and click `Open anyway` button.

[image]

Otherwise. Check some other alternative in this post: (do not forget to remove the quarantine extended attribute that’s set on the app):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457958/visual-studio-code-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have already tried this.